# CSS Button Problem with Enter Key

Tags: html, css

I made login page with CSS submit button, the problem is I have to click the button (using mouse) and can't use enter key to process my page.

This is my code:

`<a onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit();"><div id="loginButton" type="submit">LOGIN</div></a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a normal submit or `button[type="submit"]`.

The latter you can style to look like anything.

Then you don't need to use JavaScript at all.